# HTML navigation tab visible but not clickable

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with the navigation tabs on my website. I can select the tab by clicking the appropriate, linked image on every tab except for the final one (tab6). There are no hidden objects on top of it, and tab6 is the only one with issues. Appropriate code snips below, Thanks!

HTML snippet:

```
<ul id="tabs">
        <li id="tab1"><a href="http://weather.uncc.edu/"> <img src="../src/button_home.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_home_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_home.png'" height="10%" width="10%"> </a></li>
        <li id="tab2"><a href="http://brianmagiweatheruncc.dreamhosters.com/obs/"><img src="../src/button_obs.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_obs_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_obs.png'" height="10%" width="10%"></a></li>
        <li id="tab3"><a href="http://brianmagiweatheruncc.dreamhosters.com/models"><img src="../src/button_models.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_models_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_models.png'" height="10%" width="10%"></a></li>
        <li id="tab4"><a href="http://brianmagiweatheruncc.dreamhosters.com/radar/"><img src="../src/button_radar_push.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_radar_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_radar_push.png'" height="10%" width="10%"></a></li>
        <li id="tab5"><a href="https://brianmagiweatheruncc.dreamhosters.com/"><img src="../src/button_station.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_station_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_station.png'" height="10%" width="10%"></a></li>
        <li id="tab6"><a href="https://weather.uncc.edu/faq/"><img src="../src/button_contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='../src/button_contact_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../src/button_contact.png'" height="10%" width="10%"></a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS snippet:

```
#tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }  
#tabs li {
 display:inline; width:192px; height:50px;
 }
 #tabs li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0.05em 0.05em;
 }
```

Comment: if you could make working fiddle for this would help yourself by helping others to clearly see the problem

Comment: Here's your code: http://jsfiddle.net/LtLbm6tn/. What's wrong? Seems to work just fine.

Comment: If I set position:absolute then the problem disappears. Perhaps there is an issue with other devs set as absolute?

Comment: You may have some other element overlapping it..  Set position:absolute or relative with a z-index and see if the problem persists.

Comment: setting a z-index under relative doesn't seem to make a difference. I used the inspector in Firefox to see if I could identify any other elements, but it seems to confirm that everything is where it should be. The problem is fixed by setting the position to absolute (I just have to adjust other objects' positions). You're right though, clearly something is blocking the button. It just seems odd..